# C# - TextRenderer.MeasureText is a few pixels too wide

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, drawing

I'm using TextRendere.MeasureText instead of Graphics.MeasureString because it allows me to specify TextFormatFlags.NoPadding, but its return width is a few pixels to wide. For a four character text string its five pixels over and for a five character text string its six pixels over. I'm sure its going to be even more with longer text strings. I'm using .Net 4.5.1. Here's my code:

```
Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(items[a], new Font("Segoe UI", 12, GraphicsUnit.Pixel), new Size(Width, 15), TextFormatFlags.NoPadding);
```

How do I get the exact (+- 1/2px is ok) text width? Thanks :D

Comment: Sounds like it is n Number of characters + 1. You could go the hacky route and do: items[a].Length + 1

Comment: I imagine its just the Text Glyph that has extra whitespace.

Comment: +gmiley no the maximum number of added pixels is seven.

Comment: +Alex Anderson how do i remove that extra whitespace?

Comment: maybe your source text contains linebreaks and thus an extra character is counted

Comment: @user613326 no it doesn't

Comment: add size = size -(int)string.length(yourtext)

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to popular believe `Graphics.MeasureString` is the better choice to measure short strings without getting extra space.

You need to use the  `StringFormat GenericTypographic`:

```
SizeF stringSize = new SizeF();
stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(items[a], 
                                      new Font("Segoe UI", 12, GraphicsUnit.Pixel), 
                                      new SizeF(Width, 15f), 
                                      StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
```

Here is a quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms142108%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  :

> The MeasureString method is designed for use with individual strings
>   and includes a small amount of extra space before and after the string
>   to allow for overhanging glyphs. Also, the DrawString method adjusts
>   glyph points to optimize display quality and might display a string
>   narrower than reported by MeasureString. To obtain metrics suitable
>   for adjacent strings in layout (for example, when implementing
>   formatted text), use the MeasureCharacterRanges method or one of the
>   MeasureString methods that takes a StringFormat, and pass
>   GenericTypographic. Also, ensure the TextRenderingHint for the
>   Graphics is AntiAlias.

I would also suggest using SizeF if you plan to add up sizes.