# Positioning and highlighting of TreeView node text with OwnerDrawText mode

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, treeview

#### My Problem

I'm trying to create a `TreeView` that will bold portions of node text that match a search term.  My code was adopted from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63100648/combobox-ownerdrawvariable-font-format-size-problem).  I have the same/similar problem with or without an `ImageList` used, but I'll post the unused version here.  When I render my text, I get something like this where the last part of the text is cut off, but **only** for some of the nodes.  i.e. *Version* looks ok, but the rest have differing amounts of text cut off from the bounds.

[image]

I think my `TextFormatFlags` flags are affecting this, but if I don't pass those in during Measure/Render of the text, the node cuts off on the left.

If I draw my bold text, I additionally have *vertical* spacing issues introduced.  You can see when I use *Plan* as the search term, it is a bit higher than the rest of the text.

[image]

If I select a node, you can see I then get horizonal spacing issues again.

[image]

#### My Questions

1. Horizontal sizing issues of nodes rendering without bold
2. Vertical sizing issues of nodes rendering with bold portions
3. Horizontal sizing issues of nodes rendering with bold *and* active.

#### Updated Code

Thanks to @jimi, I was able to firm up some stuff.  I got close while he was answering, but below are my changes due to his suggestions.  I did do a few things differently than he did.

1. I immediately exit `tree_DrawNode` when `( formClosing || e.Bounds.X == -1 )` is true to avoid some graphical glitches.  You can see my comment below.
2. I liked how `BuildDrawingString` cleaned up the code.  I added a Width property that is calculated and additionally I fixed a bug about the return of matched text.
3. I drew the highlight background when a node had focus and window background when it doesn't to better emulate default `TreeView` behavior.  Especially when mousing down on a node, and mousing up somewhere else.
4. Instead of just using `e.Bounds` to draw background rectangle I created my own rectangle based on e.Node.Bounds x/y, the required width for rendered text, and a little padding.

   ```
   private void tree_DrawNode( object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e )
   {
       var textPadding = 2;

       // formClosing - don't need to redraw when shutting down, avoids seeing a little glitch with text offset
       // e.Bounds.X == -1 - when form loads, all *non-top level* nodes seem to draw on top of each other on first line
       //                    causing a big 'black blur' to happen when form loads b/c text is mashed together
       if ( formClosing || e.Bounds.X == -1 )
       {
           return;
       }

       using ( var boldFont = new Font( tree.Font, FontStyle.Bold ) )
       {
           var stringParts = BuildDrawingString( e, fieldSearch.Text, boldFont ).ToArray();

           // To better emulate default behavior, draw the 'selected' look only when focused, so if
           // you click down on item, originally selected item draws 'normal' and item clicking on is 'selected'
           // and if you let up on mouse outside of node, it reverts back to how it was.
           var isSelected = e.State.HasFlag( TreeNodeStates.Focused );
           var color = isSelected ? Color.White : tree.ForeColor;

           // Use e.NodeBounds X,Y and width of measured text with just a little bit of 
           // padding on left and right, e.Bounds was too wide.
           var nodeRectangle = new Rectangle(
                   e.Node.Bounds.X,
                   e.Node.Bounds.Y,
                   stringParts.Sum( p => p.Width ) + textPadding * 2,
                   e.Node.Bounds.Height
               );

           e.Graphics.FillRectangle( isSelected ? SystemBrushes.Highlight : SystemBrushes.Window, nodeRectangle );

           if ( isSelected )
           {
               using ( var focusPen = new Pen( Color.Black ) { DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dot } )
               {
                   nodeRectangle.Size = new Size( nodeRectangle.Width - 1, nodeRectangle.Height - 1 );
                   e.Graphics.DrawRectangle( focusPen, nodeRectangle );
               }
           }

           var point = new Point( e.Node.Bounds.X + textPadding, e.Node.Bounds.Y );

           foreach ( var part in stringParts )
           {
               var font = part.Selected ? boldFont : tree.Font;
               RenderNodeText( part.Text, e, font, point, color );
               point.Offset( part.Width, 0 );
           }
       }
   }

   private void RenderNodeText( string text, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e, Font font, Point offset, Color color )
   {
       var size = e.Node.Bounds.Size;
       var rect = new Rectangle( offset, size );
       TextRenderer.DrawText( e.Graphics, text, font, rect, color, e.Node.BackColor, treeFlags );
   }

   private IEnumerable<(string Text, bool Selected, int Width)> BuildDrawingString( DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e, string pattern, Font boldFont )
   {
       var itemContent = e.Node.Text;

       int measureText( string t, bool s ) => TextRenderer.MeasureText( e.Graphics, t, s ? boldFont : tree.Font, e.Bounds.Size, treeFlags ).Width;

       if ( pattern.Length == 0 )
       {
           yield return (itemContent, false, measureText( itemContent, false ));
       }
       else
       {
           var matches = Regex.Split( itemContent, $"(?i){pattern}" );
           var currentCharacter = 0;
           var patternLength = pattern.Length;

           for ( int i = 0; i < matches.Length; i++ )
           {
               if ( matches[ i ].Length >= 0 )
               {
                   yield return (
                       matches[ i ], 
                       false, 
                       measureText( matches[ i ], false ) 
                   );

                   currentCharacter += matches[ i ].Length;
               }

               if ( i < matches.Length - 1 )
               {
                   var matchText = itemContent.Substring( currentCharacter, patternLength );
                   yield return (
                       matchText,
                       true,
                       measureText( matchText, true )
                   );

                   currentCharacter += patternLength;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

#### New Twist

I moved all the final code created here from a WinForms Application to a Form inside a VSTO Word AddIn project/form and the font rendering is different for some reason.

1. The font in general (normal font) looks thinner and smaller.
2. The bold font seems offset a bit higher than the normal font.

In the image below, the top form is the one from Word and the second one (caption of Form1) is my WinForms application.  Is there some compatability issue or something when running as a VSTO add-in?

[image]

#### Original Code

```
    private void Form1_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        tree.DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText;
        tree.DrawNode += tree_DrawNode;
        tree.Font = new Font( "Microsoft YaHei UI", 10F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, 0 );
        // tree.ImageList = imageList;
        tree.Nodes.Add( "PlanInfo" );
        tree.Nodes[ 0 ].Nodes.Add( "Version" );
        tree.Nodes[ 0 ].Nodes.Add( "Plan Name" );
        tree.Nodes[ 0 ].Nodes.Add( "Plan Sponsor" );
    }

    TextFormatFlags treeFlags = TextFormatFlags.Top | TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.NoPadding;

    private void tree_DrawNode( object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e )
    {
        var currentX = 0;
        var searchText = e.Node.Text;
        var searchTerm = fieldSearch.Text;
        var matches = Regex.Split( searchText, "(?i)" + searchTerm );
        var point = new Point( e.Node.Bounds.X + currentX, e.Node.Bounds.Y );
        var isSelected = ( e.State & TreeNodeStates.Selected ) != 0;
        var color = isSelected ? Color.White : tree.ForeColor;

        if ( isSelected )
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle( SystemBrushes.Highlight, e.Node.Bounds );
        }

        if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( searchTerm ) && matches != null )
        {
            var currentCharacter = 0;
            var currentMatch = 0;
            var keyLength = searchTerm.Length;

            foreach ( var m in matches )
            {
                if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( m ) )
                {
                    point.Offset(
                        RenderNodeText( m, e, FontStyle.Regular, point, color ).Width,
                        0
                    );

                    currentCharacter += m.Length;
                }

                currentMatch++;

                if ( currentMatch < matches.Length || ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( m ) && currentMatch == 1 ) )
                {
                    var boldText = searchText.Substring( currentCharacter, keyLength );

                    point.Offset(
                        RenderNodeText( boldText, e, FontStyle.Bold, point, color ).Width,
                        0
                    );

                    currentCharacter += keyLength;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            RenderNodeText( e.Node.Text, e, FontStyle.Regular, point, color );
        }
    }

    private Size RenderNodeText( string text, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e, FontStyle altStyle, Point offset, Color color )
    {
        using ( var font = new Font( tree.Font, altStyle ) )
        {
            var size = e.Node.Bounds.Size;
            var textWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText( e.Graphics, text, font, size, treeFlags );
            var rect = new Rectangle( offset, size );
            TextRenderer.DrawText( e.Graphics, text, font, rect, color, Color.Transparent, treeFlags );
            return textWidth;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `e.Node.Bounds` can't be used as your highlight rectangle for a bold item since `e.Node` doesn't know it's using a different font.  You have to adjust the size of that rectangle with `TextRendered.MeasureText`

Comment: Working on that now, but I don't know the size until after I render text.  But if I FillRectangle then it is on top of text.  Is my only option to loop through once getting measurement only, then draw background, then loop through again and measure/draw text?

Comment: Measure first, then draw — it's that simple.  I can't make heads or tails out of your for-each loop.  You are drawing one node, why the loop?

Comment: I'm looping 'matches' in the Node text so I can draw matches in bold and other parts regular.  So PlanInfo if you searched for 'N' would look like Pla**n**I**n**fo.

Comment: Oh, so it's more `RenderNodeCharacter`.  In that case, you are almost better off writing a little dictionary of letters with their pre-rendered measurements for bold and plain.  The vertical alignment is off because of `TextFormatFlags.Top`.  You probably should try `VerticalCenter` instead (my guess).

Comment: I'll assume `RenderNodeCharacter` is a term you made up?  I can't find it anywhere.  And you are right about `VerticalCenter`, thanks.

Comment: Yes, I renamed your method.

Comment: You may want to study [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63100648/combobox-ownerdrawvariable-font-format-size-problem/63103375#63103375)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the information found in the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63100648/combobox-ownerdrawvariable-font-format-size-problem) didn't make the cut.

- [TextFormatFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textformatflags) are important: these settings have a great impact on how the Text is rendered. Also, each Control has its own specific requirements, maybe the difference is small - as in this case - but we need to adapt anyway.
  The TreeView Control is better served when the Text is align to left and centered vertically.
- [TextRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer) is very precise, but we want to give it hand (as described before) always using Rectangles as the reference container to both measure and draw the Text.  Possibly, don't use a Point, you'll notice that the results can change in similar situation when this simple reference is used. When drawing on a Control, we really don't want that.
- You removed `TextFormatFlags.NoClipping` from the original code, not good, this is a keeper. Unless you actually want to clip the Text, but then you need to specify how to clip it. Other flags can be combined for that.

Specific to this question:

- [**`e.State == TreeNodeStates.Selected`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treenodestates) is not enough, we also need to test [**`TreeNodeStates.Focused`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treenodestates), otherwise we have a *weird* difference in the Text rendering when a Node is selected or focused; these are different states: one Node can be selected and a different one focused, both must be rendered equally.
- There's a subtle difference between the Graphics bound of the  [**`DrawTreeNodeEventArgs`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.drawtreenodeeventargs) and the bounds of the Node item. When drawing the background, the former is used, to define the constraint of the Node text, the latter is used instead.
- Using Font with different weights for the same section of Text, we must use the bounds of the Node as the starting position, use the measures returned by [**`TextRenderer.MeasureText`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext), sum these measures and offset the text position *manually* (as mentioned, counting on the precision of  **`MeasureText`**).
- Whether the Node has an image is not really important, we just need to account for the initial offset, equal to **`e.Node.Bounds.X`**. In code, it's stored in **`int drawingPosition = e.Node.Bounds.X;`**.

Visual result:

[image: TreeView custom drawing TextRenderer]

---

```
TextFormatFlags twFormat = TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | 
                           TextFormatFlags.NoClipping | TextFormatFlags.NoPadding;

private void tree_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    Color textColor = e.Node.ForeColor;
    Color backColor = e.Node.BackColor == Color.Empty ? tree.BackColor : e.Node.BackColor;

    if (e.State.HasFlag(TreeNodeStates.Selected) || e.State.HasFlag(TreeNodeStates.Focused)) {
        textColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
        backColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
    }
    using (var brush = new SolidBrush(backColor)) {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);
    }

    string searchText = fieldSearch.Text;  // Search string from TextBox
    int drawingPosition = e.Node.Bounds.X;
    foreach (var part in BuildDrawingString(e.Node.Text, searchText)) {
        var style = part.Selected ? FontStyle.Bold : FontStyle.Regular;
        drawingPosition += RenderNodeText(part.Text, e, style, new Point(drawingPosition, e.Node.Bounds.Y), textColor).Width;
    }
}

private Size RenderNodeText(string text, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e, FontStyle altStyle, Point offset, Color foreColor)
{
    using (var font = new Font(tree.Font, altStyle)) {
        var size = e.Node.Bounds.Size;
        var textWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText(e.Graphics, text, font, size, twFormat);
        var rect = new Rectangle(offset, size);
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, text, font, rect, foreColor, e.Node.BackColor, twFormat);
        return textWidth;
    }
}

private IEnumerable<(string Text, bool Selected)> BuildDrawingString(string itemContent, string pattern)
{
    if (pattern.Length == 0) {
        yield return (itemContent, false);
    }
    else {
        var matches = Regex.Split(itemContent, $"(?i){pattern}");
        int pos = itemContent.IndexOf(pattern, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
        for (int i = 0; i < matches.Length; i++) {
            if (matches[i].Length == 0 && i < matches.Length - 1) {
                yield return (itemContent.Substring(pos, pattern.Length), matches[i].Length > 0 ? false : true);
            }
            else {
                yield return (matches[i], false);
                if (i < matches.Length - 1) {
                    yield return (itemContent.Substring(pos, pattern.Length), true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I updated question with my updated code and changes I made to your suggestions to make it function a bit better.  You can read those above.  Going for the tri-fecta.  Will post question about ListView, but I'm afraid that one is going to be the toughest.

Comment: No.  Not against it.  Thought that was for others and I just mark 'answered'.  But I can upvote. :)

Comment: BTW, I'll update this code, it can be improved here and there. I'll ping you when I do.

Comment: Great.  Can't wait to see.  And here is my finale (or better said, maybe *your* finale) ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63146058/listview-subitem-ownerdraw-bold-part-of-the-text

Comment: Shot in the dark.  This was all working well in a WinForms Application.  I just copied the code/controls to a form inside a VSTO Addin for Word and the font rendering is messed up a bit.  Any idea?  I'll update question with an image.