# ListView SubItem OwnerDraw Bold Part of the Text

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, graphics

To finish off my adventure of owner drawing C# controls, my last problem is in a `ListView`.  I have a `ListView` that will always be in the Detail view mode with two columns - Name and Value.  For the *Name* column, I'll always use `DefaultDraw`, and for the Value column, I want to bold every match of a search term.

My [`TreeView` question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63121949/positioning-and-highlighting-of-treeview-node-text-with-ownerdrawtext-mode) and my [`ComboBox` question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63100648/combobox-ownerdrawvariable-font-format-size-problem) about owner drawing helped shape the code so far.  I don't need any background or border drawing so it is simpler than some of the other questions I've seen people ask, but I have problem that I'm noticing so far.

When I shrink a column and expect a `...`, if I've rendered multiple string parts (because of a match from the search term), each string has its own `...` based on when it is longer than the column's width.  If there is no presence of the search term and I render the `e.SubItem.Text` as one normal string, it behaves as expected.

In the series below, *Address 1* is a complete string.  The other two items have strings of *110 M*, **aple**, and *Avenue*.

Is there a way to make the entire string act as a single entity with regards to `...`?  In my brief testing, I haven't found any other issues yet, but happy to take some advice if needed.

**Before Resize**

[image]

**First Resize - Only Address 1 shows `...`**

[image]

**Second Resize - Avenue Shows `...`**

[image]

**Third Resize - 110 M Shows `...`**

[image]

**Final Resize - Every 'string' Shows `...`**

[image]

#### Code

```
    TextFormatFlags subItemFlags = TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.Bottom | TextFormatFlags.EndEllipsis | TextFormatFlags.NoPadding;

    private void InitializeListView()
    {
        listView.OwnerDraw = true;
        listView.DrawColumnHeader += listView_DrawColumnHeader;
        listView.DrawSubItem += listView_DrawSubItem;
        listView.Font = new Font( "Microsoft YaHei UI", 10F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, 0 );
    }

    private void listView_DrawColumnHeader( object sender, DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e ) => e.DrawDefault = true;
    private void listView_DrawSubItem( object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e )
    {
        if ( e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            e.DrawDefault = true;
        }
        else
        {
            var textPadding = 2;

            using ( var boldFont = new Font( listView.Font, FontStyle.Bold ) )
            {
                var stringParts = BuildDrawingString( e.SubItem.Text, e.Graphics, e.Bounds.Size, fieldSearch.Text, listView.Font, boldFont, subItemFlags ).ToArray();
                var color = listView.ForeColor;
                var point = new Point( e.SubItem.Bounds.X + textPadding, e.SubItem.Bounds.Y );

                foreach ( var part in stringParts )
                {
                    var font = part.Selected ? boldFont : listView.Font;
                    DrawText( part.Text, e.Graphics, e.SubItem.Bounds.Size, font, point, color, e.SubItem.BackColor, subItemFlags );
                    point.Offset( part.Width, 0 );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void DrawText( string text, Graphics graphics, Size size, Font font, Point offset, Color foreColor, Color backColor, TextFormatFlags formatFlags )
    {
        var rect = new Rectangle( offset, size );
        TextRenderer.DrawText( graphics, text, font, rect, foreColor, backColor, formatFlags );
    }

    private IEnumerable<(string Text, bool Selected, int Width)> BuildDrawingString( string textToRender, Graphics graphics, Size proposedSize, string pattern, Font normalFont, Font boldFont, TextFormatFlags formatFlags )
    {
        int measureText( string t, bool s ) => TextRenderer.MeasureText( graphics, t, s ? boldFont : normalFont, proposedSize, formatFlags ).Width;

        if ( pattern.Length == 0 )
        {
            yield return (textToRender, false, measureText( textToRender, false ));
        }
        else
        {
            var matches = Regex.Split( textToRender, $"(?i){pattern}" );
            var currentCharacter = 0;
            var patternLength = pattern.Length;

            for ( int i = 0; i < matches.Length; i++ )
            {
                if ( matches[ i ].Length >= 0 )
                {
                    yield return (
                        matches[ i ], 
                        false, 
                        measureText( matches[ i ], false ) 
                    );

                    currentCharacter += matches[ i ].Length;
                }

                if ( i < matches.Length - 1 )
                {
                    var matchText = textToRender.Substring( currentCharacter, patternLength );
                    yield return (
                        matchText,
                        true,
                        measureText( matchText, true )
                    );

                    currentCharacter += patternLength;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after thinking about this a bit, I realized that each text part (bold and non-bold) were being measured against the 'entire subitem' `Bounds.Size`.  I had to instead keep decreasing the allowed size for `TextRenderer.MeasureText` so it knew when to put in the `...` and then immediately stop processing additional strings as soon as any item was rendered with `...`.  So my `BuildDrawingsString` had to account for this, and it also had to return an `AllowedWidth` for each part as well, so that the actual call to `TextRenderer.DrawText` would use the correct `Size` each time as well.

```
    private void listView_DrawSubItem( object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e )
    {
        if ( e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            e.DrawDefault = true;
        }
        else
        {
            var textPadding = 2;

            using ( var boldFont = new Font( listView.Font, FontStyle.Bold ) )
            {
                var stringParts = BuildDrawingString( e.SubItem.Text, e.Graphics, e.SubItem.Bounds.Size, fieldSearch.Text, listView.Font, boldFont, subItemFlags, true );
                var color = listView.ForeColor;
                var point = new Point( e.SubItem.Bounds.X + textPadding, e.SubItem.Bounds.Y );

                foreach ( var part in stringParts )
                {
                    var font = part.Selected ? boldFont : listView.Font;
                    // System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine( e.SubItem.Bounds.Size + ", " + part.Width );
                    DrawText( part.Text, e.Graphics, new Size( part.AllowedWidth, e.SubItem.Bounds.Size.Height ), font, point, color, e.SubItem.BackColor, subItemFlags );
                    point.Offset( part.Width, 0 );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<(string Text, bool Selected, int Width, int AllowedWidth)> BuildDrawingString( string textToRender, Graphics graphics, Size proposedSize, string pattern, Font normalFont, Font boldFont, TextFormatFlags formatFlags, bool isListView )
    {
        var totalWidth = 0;
        (int width, int allowedWidth, bool isTruncated) measureText( string t, bool s )
        {
            var size = new Size( proposedSize.Width - totalWidth, proposedSize.Height );
            var width = TextRenderer.MeasureText( graphics, t, s ? boldFont : normalFont, size, formatFlags ).Width;
            var truncated = isListView && TextRenderer.MeasureText( graphics, t, s ? boldFont : normalFont, size, formatFlags & ~TextFormatFlags.EndEllipsis ).Width != width;

            return ( width, size.Width, truncated );
        }

        if ( pattern.Length == 0 )
        {
            yield return ( textToRender, false, measureText( textToRender, false ).width, proposedSize.Width );
        }
        else
        {
            var matches = Regex.Split( textToRender, $"(?i){pattern}" );
            var currentCharacter = 0;
            var patternLength = pattern.Length;

            for ( int i = 0; i < matches.Length; i++ )
            {
                if ( matches[ i ].Length >= 0 )
                {
                    var measureInfo = measureText( matches[ i ], false );
                    totalWidth += measureInfo.width;

                    yield return (
                        matches[ i ],
                        false,
                        measureInfo.width,
                        measureInfo.allowedWidth
                    );

                    currentCharacter += matches[ i ].Length;

                    if ( measureInfo.isTruncated )
                    {
                        yield break;
                    }
                }

                if ( i < matches.Length - 1 )
                {
                    var matchText = textToRender.Substring( currentCharacter, patternLength );
                    var measureInfo = measureText( matchText, true );
                    totalWidth += measureInfo.width;

                    yield return (
                        matchText,
                        true,
                        measureInfo.width,
                        measureInfo.allowedWidth
                    );

                    currentCharacter += patternLength;

                    if ( measureInfo.isTruncated )
                    {
                        yield break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```